# Nested Attributes with has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

I have 4 table with association like that.
- Course

```
class Course < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :training_frameworks, dependent: :destroy
end
```

- Training_framework:

```
class TrainingFramework < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :course

  has_many :training_subjects, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :subjects, through: :training_subjects

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :training_subjects
end
```

- Training_subject:

```
class TrainingSubject < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :subject
  belongs_to :training_framework
end
```

And Subject:

```
class Subject < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :training_subjects, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :training_frameworks, through: :training_subjects
end
```

-In a training_framework, i want create many subject through training_subject. And i have trouble with make param and use it cho create training_framwork with instance of course.
- Param i made and test in rails console:

```
param = { training_framework: { name: "version1", training_subjects_attributes: [{subject_id: 1}, {subject_id: 2}]}}
=> {:training_framework=>{:name=>"version1", :training_subject_attributes=>[{:subject_id=>1}, {:subject_id=>2}]}}
```

It run with `TrainingFramework.create(param[:traning_framework])` not `@course.training_frameworks.create(param[:traning_framework])`

Where was i wrong  and how to fix it?
What's keywork for seach to use association with 4 table ?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @MikhailKatrin sorry, it's my mistake. I want create training_framework of a course has many subject use nested attribute. How i do this?

Answer (score 0):

`course` is assosiated with `training_framework`. You have to specify for which `course` you want to create `training_framework`.

Don't forget to permit param `course_id` (or `course`) if you use strong params.

```
param = {
    course_id: <course_id>, # <--
    training_framework: {
        name: "version1",
        training_subjects_attributes: [
            {subject_id: 1},
            {subject_id: 2}
        ]
    }
}
```

---

```
TrainingFramework.create(param[:traning_framework])
```

Or you could create `training_framework` first and then assign to appropriate `course`.

Check that `training_framework` is actually created for appropriate `course`: `Course.find(<course_id>).training_framework`

Comment: i'm done in console. It's run. Thank you very much.  And have problem in view new. I want to select subject by check box. How can't i render collection check box use fields_for  with value from @subject ?

Comment: `<% @subject.map %> ...checkbox view... <% end %>`